# Unable to install CiviCRM plugin

Tags: wordpress, installation

Wordpress 4.5.2
CiviCRM 4.7.7
PHP 5.5.34

The installation goes smoothly and the database is created but I cannot continue with the configuration. I get this screen:

*CiviCRM Home
Configure Your Dashboard Refresh Dashboard Data
Welcome to your Home Dashboard
Your dashboard provides a one-screen view of the data that's most important to you. Graphical or tabular data is pulled from the reports you select, and is displayed in 'dashlets' (sections of the dashboard).

Access Keys: 
Powered by CiviCRM 4.7.7. System Status: Error CiviCRM is openly available under the GNU AGPL License.
Download CiviCRM.     View issues and report bugs.     Online documentation.
It says System Status: Error but where to look for errors?*

Comment: I should see the page to configure the rest of the CiviCRM setup

Comment: Can you see a CiviCRM menu bar overlaying the wp-admin bar?